# How to validate if all check boxes are ticked in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am a beginner in jQuery and I was wondering how to validate the form before submission specifically for check boxes.

I am creating a simple check list form where my user would tick a check box if he finished that step. What I am planning to do is that, the script would prevent the form submission if there is an "unticked" checkbox and highlight it with a color.

Here's my code :

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <style>
      .error {
        background-color: #F00;
      }
      .valid {
        background-color: #0F0;
      }
    </style>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js">    </script>
    <script type="application/javascript">
      $('#button').on('click', function() {
        var $checkboxes = $('.container [type=checkbox]');

        $checkboxes.filter(':checked').parent().removeClass('error').addClass('valid');
        $checkboxes.not(':checked').parent().removeClass('valid').addClass('error');
      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <input class="tick" id="option1" type="checkbox">
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <input class="tick" id="option1" type="checkbox">
    </div>
    <input id="button" type="button" value="check">
  </body>
</html>
```

So what I am trying to do here is when the user clicks the button, the script will highlight all the unchecked check box with red and highlight all checked with green.

However, my script is not functioning. What is wrong with my script? Any suggestions on a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var len = $('input[type=checkbox]').length;

    $('#button').click(function(e){
        var $cb = $('input[type=checkbox]');
        $cb.filter(':checked').parent().removeClass('error');
        var not = $cb.not(':checked').parent().addClass('error').length;
        if (len == not) {
            e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default action of the event
        }
    })​
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2dcPE/

Note that your markup is not valid, IDs must be unique.

Comment: @Jashwant For checking length of unselected checkboxes.

Comment: @Jashwant Yes, I had missed the length property :). But it want't an error.

Comment: This works at jsFiddle, however, it doesn't work it my code. When I checked using Firebug, it says `SyntaxError: illegal character` `});`

Comment: @Jude That is not related to this code, there is a syntax error somewhere else.

Comment: @Jude There is no error in that code. Put your codes inside document ready handler.

Comment: Oh yeah, completely forgot about that! Thank you @undefined!

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple elements with identical `id` attributes. `id`s are unique and should refer to one element. If you plan on grouping multiple elements together, use a `class` attribute instead.

Also, don't bind events using `onclick`. Just use the jQuery `.on('click'` handler.

**HTML**:

```
<div class="container">
    <input class="tick" id="option1" type="checkbox" />
</div>

<div class="container">
    <input class="tick" id="option2" type="checkbox" />
</div>

<input id="button" type="button" value="check" />​
```

**JavaScript**:

```
$('#button').on('click', function() {
    var $checkboxes = $('.container [type=checkbox]');

    $checkboxes.filter(':checked').parent().removeClass('error').addClass('valid');
    $checkboxes.not(':checked').parent().removeClass('valid').addClass('error');
});​
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Blender/fzZFz/3/**

Comment: This works at jsFiddle, however, it doesn't work it my code. When I checked using Firebug, it says SyntaxError: illegal character });

Comment: I have updated the code on the question, and I don't see any extra }); on the code.

Comment: Are you positive that's *all* of your code? Also, you never wrapped the code in a `$(document).ready(function() { ... });` block.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function validateAll(){
    $('.tick').each(function(){
        if(this.checked){
            $(this).closest('#container').addClass('valid');
        }else{
            $(this).closest('#container').addClass('error');
        }
        });
    }
```

See live [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qDx9t/)

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

1.) you have multiple elements with the same ID (container).  That is not valid html and jquery will only return the first element it finds when searching by ID.

2.) You are binding an event to the change only after the user clicks the check button.  I think you could just bind to the .tick change event and have it validate as the user is checking items.

3.) Your logic was backwards for validation.   You were adding the error condition when everything was valid.

The final js is this:

```
    $(".tick").change(function(){
        if ($('.tick:checked').length == $('.tick').length) {
            $('.container').removeClass("error");
            $('.container').addClass('valid');
        } else {
            $('.container').removeClass("valid");
            $('.container').addClass('error');
        }
});    ​
```

With a small tweak to the html to remove the duplicate IDs:

```
<div class="container"><input class="tick" id="option1" type="checkbox"></div>
<div class="container"><input class="tick" id="option1" type="checkbox"></div>
```

See this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/johnkoer/225Ty/5/

Answer (score 0):

```
function validateAll() {
    $(".tick").each(function(index, item) {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $(this).parent().removeClass().addClass('valid');
        } else {
            $(this).parent().removeClass().addClass('error');
        }
    });
}
```